# PyQt5 QWidget event blocks other events. How to avoid it?

Tags: python, events, pyqt, pyqt5

I have the next problem:

A created a custom widget (simple derived QWidget class). When I middle-mouse click on it - it creates another QWidget class (sort of context menu). When I release middle-mouse button - that context widget disappears. So that works. What does not work is - that context widget also has some content added, like other small widgets, icons, etc and they all have their own custom events (simple example - enterEvent and leaveEvent with prints indicating those events). But those inner widget events are not working, they are blocked while I keep middle-mouse pressed. When I release it - context widget disappears. Would like to know if there is any solution to let inner widgets'events work as expected.

Here is a minimal example where inner widget does not run mouse events as they are blocked by MainWidget event:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class SomeSmallWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, increment=1, globalValue=0):
        super(SomeSmallWidget, self).__init__()

        # UI
        self.setMinimumWidth(40)
        self.setMaximumWidth(40)
        self.setMinimumHeight(40)
        self.setMaximumHeight(40)

        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        print('Entered')  # NOT WORKING
        super(SomeSmallWidget, self).enterEvent(event)
    
    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        print('Leaved') # NOT WORKING
        super(SomeSmallWidget, self).leaveEvent(event)


class ContextWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ContextWidget, self).__init__()

        self.setMouseTracking(True)

        # position
        point = parent.rect().topLeft()
        global_point = parent.mapToGlobal(point)
        self.move(global_point - QtCore.QPoint(0, 0))

        self.innerWidget = SomeSmallWidget() # Here is that small widget, which event does not work

        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.innerWidget)
 

class MainWidget(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):

    def __init__(self, value='0'):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.popMenu = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton: # while we keep MMB pressed - we see context widget
            self.popMenu = ContextWidget(parent=self)
            self.popMenu.show()
        super(MainWidget, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton:
            if self.popMenu:
                self.popMenu = None
```

Answer (score 0):

Events are not blocked, all mouse events are sent to widget that was under cursor when mouse button was pressed. Usually (always) it makes more sense. Imagine two buttons next to each other. Suppose user pressed one, moved cursor and released over second button. What was his intention? He probably changed his mind. If button triggers action on mouse press - this options will not be available and it's probably too soon, if button triggers action on mouse release, which button should recieve mouserelease event? If we send mouseevent to second button - that was not pressed it will trigger action that used didn't want. If we dont send mouserelease event to first button - it will stay in sunken mode. Imagine user is selecting text in lineedit, and while selecting he leaves lineedit and goes to other widgets, should they react somehow, and should focus be switched? Probably not. So there is only one active window and only one focused widget at a time and it receives keyboard and mouse input and reacts to it. Most of menus are shown after mouserelease and closes on next mouseclick, providing better user experience.

However, If you still want your widget to receive mouse events, you can achive this by translating it from `ContextWidget` to `SomeSmallWidget` like this:

```
class SomeSmallWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    ...
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.fillRect(self.rect(), QtCore.Qt.blue)

    def onMouseEnter(self):
        print('onMouseEnter')

    def onMouseLeave(self):
        print('onMouseLeave')

class MainWidget(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    ...
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.popMenu:
            self.popMenu.mouseTest(event.globalPos())

class ContextWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ...
        self._inside = False

    def mouseTest(self, p):
        widget = self.innerWidget
        rect = QtCore.QRect(widget.mapToGlobal(QtCore.QPoint(0,0)), widget.size())
        inside = rect.contains(p)
        if inside != self._inside:
            if inside:
                widget.onMouseEnter()
            else:
                widget.onMouseLeave()
        self._inside = inside
```

Notice I added `paintEvent` to see the widget bounds.

Comment: A small suggestion: you don't need to create a new QRect in the paintEvent, just call `self.rect()`; you also don't need to create a new brush if you're using `Qt.GlobalColors`, so you can just use `painter.fillRect(self.rect(), QtCore.Qt.blue)`. Besides that, some clarifications: 1. all mouse events are sent to the widget on which the mouse press happened because it becomes the *mouseGrabber*, but that can be overridden; 2. active window and focused window/widget are not always related, and can be independent from keyboard focus; 3. context menus appear on mouse press, not release.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Turns out context menus on some platforms appear on mouse press on others on mouse release [qwidgetwindow.cpp:505](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/c773fd297abd5ae0f5bc1148c289f41066bf3fd8/src/widgets/kernel/qwidgetwindow.cpp#L505) for example on windows i dont see any menu until I release a button